# Can't format the table correctly (\hline and colored cells)

Tags: tables, booktabs, colortbl, cellcolor

I've created this table using a table converter website online and then tweaking it until I got what I wanted. I am using overleaf to compile everything.

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Composition of the study sample in the pre-Black Death period by site.}\label{Table5.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llccccc@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Region}& \textbf{Site}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Early pre-}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Late pre-}}& \textbf{Total}\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Black Death}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Black Death}}& \textbf{}\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{}& \textbf{n}& \textbf{\%}& \textbf{n}& \textbf{\%}& \textbf{N}\\ \hline
\textbf{Extra-London} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Wharram Percy}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}7& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}12.07 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}51& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}87.93 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}58\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{St Oswald's}& 44& 29.33 & 106 & 70.67 & 150 \\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{St Anne's Charterhouse} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{Barton Upon Humber}& 197 & 66.33 & 100 & 33.67 & 297 \\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Stoke Quay}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}191 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}35.97 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}340 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}64.03 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}531 \\ \cline{2-7} 
\textbf{}& \textbf{Subtotal}& 439 & 42.37 & 597 & 57.63 & 1036 \\
\midrule
\textbf{London}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Guildhall Yard}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}10& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}27.03 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}27& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}72.97 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}37\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{East Smithfield}& 0&& 0&& 0\\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Merton Priory}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}37& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}100& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}37\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{St Mary Graces}& 0&& 0&& 0\\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Spital Square} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}40& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6} 100 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}40\\ \cline{2-7} 
\textbf{}& \textbf{Subtotal}& 10& 8.77& 104 & 91.23 & 114 \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & & 449 & 39.04 & 701 & 60.96 & 1150\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The table looks messy, but it compiles.
The issue that I have is that after compiling, the table looks like this:

[image: Table showing how the previous code compiles]

It has all the information I want, but I have a few issues:

1. All lines came out right except the second one on top of Extra-London. It should go across the whole graph, but it only covers one cell.
2. There is a small white gap under the midline )the one that starts with London). I have seen this a lot and don't know how to remove it.
3. The colored cells extend further than the lines and margin. I want the lines and cells to have the same limit at the end of the page's margins.
4. I can't be sure but it looks like all the cells don't have the same height, The second subtotal looks shorter than the first one (I may be wrong).

How can I fix these issues? Any advice will be welcomed.

Thank you,
Sincerely,

Comment: Can you please make your code snippet be compilable? Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: `\textbf{}` does nothing, you could simply delete them all, mak your source look a lot more reasonable please see the `colortbl` documentation, `\cline` is explicitly not supported. There are things you coud do (use `hhline`, or  use  different table markup such as `tabularray` But are you _sure_ you want rules and coloured panels, I'd just not use the rules

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't mix `\hline` with `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` because the latter three (which are defined by the `booktabs` package) have a different spacing. In the case of colored cells, this spacing may look odd.

Comment: urelated but don't use `[h!]` unless you really need an exceptional over-ride (`!`)

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix-and-mismatch visual grouping idioms: If you use colored (or gray) rows, don't use horizontal lines, and vice versa. I recommend you simply omit all `\hline` directives and replace most `\midrule` directives with `\addlinespace`.

I would also get rid of all **bold-facing**. It's simply not needed, and it does worsen the table's legibility. If you must highlight select words (such as "Subtotal" and "Total", use `\textsc` for small-caps. And, I'd align the numbers in the 5 data columns on their expicit or implicit decimal markers, using the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
%!TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\mycolor{\cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{siunitx} % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\extrarowheight{1pt} % for a less-cramped look
\centering
\caption{Composition of study sample in pre-Black Death period, by site.\strut}
\label{Table5.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll T{3.0} T{2.2} T{3.0} T{3.2} T{4.0}}
\toprule
Region & Site & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Early pre-} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Late pre-} & Total \\
& & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Black Death} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Black Death}& \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
& & {$n$} & {\%} & {$n$} & {\%} & {$N$} \\ 
\addlinespace
Extra-London & 
  \mycolor Wharram Percy& \mycolor 7& \mycolor 12.07 & \mycolor 51& \mycolor 87.93 & \mycolor 58\\
& St Oswald's & 44& 29.33 & 106 & 70.67 & 150 \\
& \mycolor St Anne's Charterhouse & \mycolor 0& \mycolor & \mycolor 0& \mycolor & \mycolor 0\\
& Barton Upon Humber& 197 & 66.33 & 100 & 33.67 & 297 \\
& \mycolor Stoke Quay& \mycolor 191 & \mycolor 35.97 & \mycolor 340 & \mycolor 64.03 & \mycolor 531 \\
& \textsc{Subtotal} & 439 & 42.37 & 597 & 57.63 & 1036 \\
\addlinespace
London & 
  \mycolor Guildhall Yard& \mycolor 10& \mycolor 27.03 & \mycolor 27& \mycolor 72.97 & \mycolor 37\\
& East Smithfield & 0&& 0&& 0\\
& \mycolor Merton Priory& \mycolor 0& \mycolor 0& \mycolor 37& \mycolor 100& \mycolor 37\\
& St Mary Graces & 0&& 0&& 0\\
& \mycolor Spital Square & \mycolor 0 & \mycolor & \mycolor 40& \mycolor 100 & \mycolor 40\\  
& \textsc{Subtotal}& 10& 8.77& 104 & 91.23 & 114 \\ 
\midrule
\textsc{Total} & & 449 & 39.04 & 701 & 60.96 & 1150\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment. You write that "Regretfully, the final table does not have the format I want." Sadly, I don't know either which format you want. ;-) But then, frankly, I've never been any good at reading other people's minds...

Speaking for myself, I can't say that the alternating gray and white rows do much to enhance and clarify the table's contents. I would therefore seriously recommend you consider ditching the alternating white/gray rows altogether -- and use more horizonal rules instead. I.e., something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,geometry,siunitx} 
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Composition of study sample in two pre-Black Death periods, by site.\strut}
\label{Table5.2}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll T{3.0} T{2.2} T{3.0} T{3.2} T{4.0} @{}}
\toprule
Region & Site &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Early pre-} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Late pre-} & {Total} \\
& &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Black Death} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Black Death}& \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6}
& & {$n$} & {\%} & {$n$} & {\%} & {$N$} \\
\midrule
Extra-London &
  Wharram Percy     &   7 & 12.07 &  51 & 87.93 &   58 \\
& St Oswald's       &  44 & 29.33 & 106 & 70.67 &  150 \\
& St Anne's Charterhouse & 0 &    &   0 &       &    0 \\
& Barton Upon Humber& 197 & 66.33 & 100 & 33.67 &  297 \\
& Stoke Quay        & 191 & 35.97 & 340 & 64.03 &  531 \\[0.5ex]
& \textsc{Subtotal} & 439 & 42.37 & 597 & 57.63 & 1036 \\
\midrule
London &
  Guildhall Yard    & 10 & 27.03 &  27 &  72.97 &   37 \\
& East Smithfield   &  0 &       &   0 &        &    0 \\
& Merton Priory     &  0 &  0    &  37 & 100    &   37 \\
& St Mary Graces    &  0 &       &   0 &        &    0 \\
& Spital Square     &  0 &       &  40 & 100    &   40 \\[0.5ex]
& \textsc{Subtotal} & 10 &  8.77 & 104 &  91.23 &  114 \\
\midrule
Total & &            449 & 39.04 & 701 &  60.96 & 1150 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful. The \mycolor command could make things much easier.
The top/mid and bottom lines were a last-minute addition when I started to have issues with \hline.
Regretfully, the final table does not have the format I want. Even if I removed the bold fonts, I still need the lines to be as I placed them. The addlinespace as you did does not work. Is there any other way to add additional lines that look exactly like the top and bottom lines?

Comment: @Flor - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Mico's answer is probably the good answer (+1) but, if you actually want to have the design you have in mind in your question, you can use `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

In the following example, I have used your code by replacing `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` (with the key `colortbl-like`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption{Composition of the study sample in the pre-Black Death period by site.}\label{Table5.2}
\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}llccccc@{}}[colortbl-like]
\toprule
\textbf{Region}& \textbf{Site}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Early pre-}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Late pre-}}& \textbf{Total}\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Black Death}}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Black Death}}& \textbf{}\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{}& \textbf{n}& \textbf{\%}& \textbf{n}& \textbf{\%}& \textbf{N}\\ \hline
\textbf{Extra-London} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Wharram Percy}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}7& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}12.07 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}51& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}87.93 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}58\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{St Oswald's}& 44& 29.33 & 106 & 70.67 & 150 \\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{St Anne's Charterhouse} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{Barton Upon Humber}& 197 & 66.33 & 100 & 33.67 & 297 \\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Stoke Quay}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}191 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}35.97 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}340 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}64.03 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}531 \\ \cline{2-7} 
\textbf{}& \textbf{Subtotal}& 439 & 42.37 & 597 & 57.63 & 1036 \\
\midrule
\textbf{London}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Guildhall Yard}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}10& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}27.03 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}27& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}72.97 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}37\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{East Smithfield}& 0&& 0&& 0\\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Merton Priory}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}37& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}100& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}37\\
\textbf{}& \textbf{St Mary Graces}& 0&& 0&& 0\\
\textbf{}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}\textbf{Spital Square} & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}0 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}40& \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6} 100 & \cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}40\\ \cline{2-7} 
\textbf{}& \textbf{Subtotal}& 10& 8.77& 104 & 91.23 & 114 \\ \hline
\textbf{Total} & & 449 & 39.04 & 701 & 60.96 & 1150\\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However, you need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

---

Here is a simplified code for the same output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Composition of the study sample in the pre-Black Death period by site.}\label{Table5.2}

\begin{NiceTabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}l>{\bfseries}lc*{4}{w{c}{9mm}}@{}}
\CodeBefore
    \rowcolors[HTML]{3-13}{E7E6E6}{}[cols=2-7]
\Body
    \toprule
    \RowStyle[nb-rows=2,bold]{} 
    Region       & Site & \Block{1-2}{Early pre-\\ Black Death} && \Block{1-2}{Late pre-\\ Black Death} && Total\\
                 &                        & n   & \%    & n   & \%    & N    \\ \hline
    Extra-London & Wharram Percy          & 7   & 12.07 & 51  & 87.93 & 58   \\
                 & St Oswald's            & 44  & 29.33 & 106 & 70.67 & 150  \\
                 & St Anne's Charterhouse & 0   &       & 0   &       & 0    \\
                 & Barton Upon Humber     & 197 & 66.33 & 100 & 33.67 & 297  \\
                 & Stoke Quay             & 191 & 35.97 & 340 & 64.03 & 531  \\ \cline{2-7} 
                 & Subtotal               & 439 & 42.37 & 597 & 57.63 & 1036 \\
    \midrule
    London       & Guildhall Yard         & 10  & 27.03 & 27  & 72.97 & 37   \\
                 & East Smithfield        & 0   &       & 0   &       & 0    \\
                 & Merton Priory          & 0   & 0     & 37  & 100   & 37   \\
                 & St Mary Graces         & 0   &       & 0   &       & 0    \\
                 & Spital Square          & 0   &       & 40  &  100  & 40   \\ \cline{2-7} 
                 & Subtotal               & 10  & 8.77  & 104 & 91.23 & 114  \\ \hline
    Total        &                        & 449 & 39.04 & 701 & 60.96 & 1150 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! I also liked the previous answer. However, it changed the format of the table too much. I've tried to use Nicematric before but had some compilation issues. I will try again.

Answer (score 1):

With `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip,
            font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mycolor{\cellcolor[HTML]{E7E6E6}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Composition of study sample in pre-Black Death period, by site.\strut}
\label{Table5.2}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {ll *{2}{S[table-format=4.1] S[table-format=2.2]}
                                S[table-format=4.0]},
             row{1} = {guard, font=\bfseries},
             row{2} = {guard, mode=math},
             cell{odd[3-X]}{2-Z} = {gray9},
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[c=1]{f}    Region  
    &   \SetCell[c=1]{f}    Site  
        &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Early pre-\\ Black Death}
            &       &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Late pre-\\ Black Death}
                            &       &   \SetCell[c=1]{f}    Total     
                                                        \\
    &       & n     & \%    & n     & \%    & N         \\

    \midrule
\SetCell[r=6]{h}   Extra-London 
    & Wharram Percy
            &   7   & 12.07 & 51    & 87.93 & 58        \\
    & St Oswald's 
            &  44   & 29.33 & 106   & 70.67 & 150       \\
    &  St Anne's Charterhouse 
            &  0&   &   0   &       &  0                \\
    & Barton Upon Humber
            & 197   & 66.33 & 100   & 33.67 & 297       \\
    & Stoke Quay
            &  191  & 35.97 &  340  & 64.03 & 531       \\
    \midrule
    & \textsc{Subtotal} 
            & 439   & 42.37 & 597   & 57.63 & 1036      \\
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=6]{h}   London 
    & Guildhall Yard
            &  10   & 27.03 &  27   & 72.97 &  37       \\
    & East Smithfield 
            & 0     &       & 0     &       & 0         \\
    &  Merton Priory
            & 0     & 0     & 37    &  100  & 37        \\
    & St Mary Graces 
            & 0     &       & 0     &       & 0         \\
    &  Spital Square 
            &  0    &       &  40   &  100  & 40       \\
    \midrule
    & \textsc{Subtotal}
            & 10    & 8.77  & 104   & 91.23 & 114       \\
    \midrule
\textsc{Total}  
    &       & 449   & 39.04 & 701   & 60.96 & 1150      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]